# "Scrapy crawl " not working from the project folder running from spiders folder

Tags: python, scrapy, google-cloud-platform, scrapyd, scrapinghub

I am newbie in Python. I have tried finding the solution everywhere but couldn't get through.

I have made a Scrapy project and because of the project structure, the spiders are by default stored in `/spiders` directory.

Problem: We generally run the crawlers from the `/project` directory which contains `/spiders` inside it. The problem started after including this piece of code:

```
def implicit():
    from google.cloud import storage

    # If you don't specify credentials when constructing theclient,the
    # client library will look for credentials in the environment.
    storage_client = storage.Client()

# Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "remote url of the json file"
```

This code above doesn't catch the remote file if I crawl the spider from the `/project` directory and throws error

> "File json_filename.json was not found."

But when i crawl the spider from `/project/spider` directory it runs smoothly without any error.

I guess I am missing some fundamentals over here, something to do with crawling location or the environment variables. 
Thanks people.

Comment: Where have you inserted the code ? Which file? Are you running scrapy from the command line ? Please clarify some details here, otherwise it is impossible to give you ans answer.

Comment: @aleroot inserted this code in a spider which is stored in /spiders directory. Also m running using command line . Scrapy crawl spidername

Comment: Do you have a json file with the credentials locally saved in `/project/spider`?

Comment: @RubénC. yes exactly.

Comment: If you are using a relative path in `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "remote url of the json file"`instead of the absolute one, it would explain why is failing launching from one folder but not from the other.